# How to Change the color of td in the table at runtime? vb.net

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I have a problem with change color when i press a button, if I put that code in page load work but i don't know why.

My code for Design page

```js
If AvrageCD < 3 And MaxCD < 3 Then
  ComplelelyDefined_Average.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Green")
  ComplelelyDefined_Max.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Green")
  ComplelelyDefined_Min.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Green")
ElseIf AvrageCD > 3 And MaxCD > 3 Then
  ComplelelyDefined_Average.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Red")
  ComplelelyDefined_Max.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Red")
  ComplelelyDefined_Min.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Red")
ElseIf AvrageCD > 3 And MaxCD < 3 Then
  ComplelelyDefined_Average.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Orange")
  ComplelelyDefined_Max.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Orange")
  ComplelelyDefined_Min.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Orange")
ElseIf AvrageCD < 3 And MaxCD > 3 Then
  ComplelelyDefined_Average.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Orange")
  ComplelelyDefined_Max.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Orange")
  ComplelelyDefined_Min.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Orange")
End If
```

I have more TDs but I put just one, I have ID for that `"ComplelelyDefined_Average"`

My other code:

```html
<td class="style1" id="ComplelelyDefined_Average" runat="server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="LBL_ComplelelyDefined_Average" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#000099"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BTN_Submit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
```

That code put me color on cell Red, green or orange. That code work in page load, but when i Press a Button Doesn't work.

I try with:

```
ComplelelyDefined_Average.Style("background-color")="red"
```

but doesn't work

I try with:

```
ComplelelyDefined_Average.Attribute("Class") = "MyCss"
```

And also I try with something else but it doesn't work

NOTE! My code work in Page load

Answer (score 0):

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/407672/How-to-Change-the-color-of-td-in-the-table-at-runt)

Try this (not tested) :

```
ComplelelyDefined_Average.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Green;");
```